# Can't open webpage with live server using remote tunnel on a phone with different wifi

Tags: remote-access, tunnel

Is there a way to connect to the vs code remote tunnel via live server using a phone with different network/wifi?

I tried opening live server on my phone but the webpage opens up in my base pc and not on my phone, even if i write the correct localhost name the webpage doesn't show up.